# java: changing focus on JTextPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I have a Calculator class that will take input from 3 out of 4 textfields and then calculate the other one using a Loan class i already made.

Now I need to add "calculator style" buttons that user can use to input these ammounts into the TextFields.  Here is what I have so far . . .

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
public static final int width = 400;
public static final int height = 300;
private JButton calculate;
private static JTextField amount;
private JTextField interest;
private JTextField term;
private JTextField payment;
private JLabel amountL;
private JLabel interestL;
private JLabel termL;
private JLabel paymentL;
private String i = "0";

public Calculator ()
{
    super("Loan Calculator");
    setSize(width, height);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    calculate = new JButton("payment");
    calculate.setFocusable(false);
    amount = new JTextField(10);
    interest = new JTextField(10);
    term = new JTextField(10);
    payment = new JTextField(10);

    JPanel numbButt = new JPanel();
    numbButt.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
    JButton zero = new JButton("0");
    zero.setFocusable(false);
    JButton one = new JButton("1");
    one.setFocusable(false);
    JButton two = new JButton("2");
    two.setFocusable(false);
    JButton three = new JButton("3");
    three.setFocusable(false);
    JButton four = new JButton("4");
    four.setFocusable(false);
    JButton five = new JButton("5");
    five.setFocusable(false);
    JButton six = new JButton("6");
    six.setFocusable(false);
    JButton seven = new JButton("7");
    seven.setFocusable(false);
    JButton eight = new JButton("8");
    eight.setFocusable(false);
    JButton nine = new JButton("9");
    nine.setFocusable(false);
    JButton period = new JButton(".");
    period.setFocusable(false);
    numbButt.add(seven);
    seven.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(eight);
    eight.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(nine);
    nine. addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(four);
    four.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(five);
    five.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(six);
    six.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(one);
    one.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(two);
    two.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(three);
    three.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(zero);
    zero.addActionListener(this);
    numbButt.add(period);
    period.addActionListener(this);
    JButton enter = new JButton("enter");
    enter.setFocusable(false);
    numbButt.add(enter);
    enter.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    amountL = new JLabel("amount");
    interestL = new JLabel("interest");
    termL = new JLabel("term");
    paymentL = new JLabel("payment");
    inputPanel.add(amountL);
    inputPanel.add(amount);
    inputPanel.add(interestL);
    inputPanel.add(interest);
    inputPanel.add(termL);
    inputPanel.add(term);
    inputPanel.add(paymentL);
    inputPanel.add(payment);
    add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    calculate.addActionListener(this);
    JButton amountB = new JButton("amount");
    amountB.setFocusable(false);
    amountB.addActionListener(this);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(calculate);
    buttonPanel.add(amountB);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(numbButt, BorderLayout.WEST);
    interest.requestFocusInWindow();

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionFocusMover();
    enter.addActionListener(actionListener);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

    String iamt, ii, iterm, ipmt;
    String buttonString = e.getActionCommand();
    Component x;
    if(buttonString.equals("1"))
        i=i+1;
    else if(buttonString.equals("2"))
        i=i+2;
    else if(buttonString.equals("3"))
        i=i+3;
    else if(buttonString.equals("4"))
        i=i+4;
    else if(buttonString.equals("5"))
        i=i+5;
    else if(buttonString.equals("6"))
        i=i+6;
    else if(buttonString.equals("7"))
        i=i+7;
    else if(buttonString.equals("8"))
        i=i+8;
    else if(buttonString.equals("9"))
        i=i+9;
    else if(buttonString.equals("0"))
        i=i+0;
    else if(buttonString.equals("."))
        i=i+".";
    else if(buttonString.equals("enter"))

    else if(buttonString.equals("payment"))
    {
        iamt = amount.getText();
        ii = interest.getText();
        iterm = term.getText();

        Loan justin = new Loan(Integer.parseInt(iterm),Double.parseDouble(ii), Double.parseDouble(iamt));

        payment.setText(Double.toString(justin.getPayment()));
    }
    else 
    {
        ii = interest.getText();
        iterm = term.getText();
        ipmt = payment.getText();

        Loan justin = new Loan(Double.parseDouble(ipmt), Integer.parseInt(iterm),Double.parseDouble(ii));

        amount.setText(Double.toString(justin.getAmount()));
    }

    amount.setText(i);
}

public static void setFocus()
{
    amount.requestFocusInWindow();
}
class ActionFocusMover implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.focusNextComponent();
      }
    }
}
```

The way I have it set up allows for the buttons to be entered into a string and then placed into a static field for the time being (amount).  What I need to know is how *edit* to check to see which object currently has focus and inputbuttonString into that oject. *edit*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [requestFocusInWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) method to set the focus on a component. Make sure the component is displayable, focusable and visible.

From [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

> If you want to ensure that a particular component gains the focus the
>   first time a window is activated, you can call the
>   requestFocusInWindow method on the component after the component has
>   been realized, but before the frame is displayed.

To setup initial focus on `Amount` field call `requestFocusInWindow` after `pack()`.

The same tutorial provides examples about `focus traversal policy` and `focus traversal keys`. For example how to add `Enter` as a focus traversal key:

```
Set forwardKeys = getFocusTraversalKeys(
    KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
Set newForwardKeys = new HashSet(forwardKeys);
newForwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS,
    newForwardKeys);
```

Alternatively, you can transfer focus in `JTextArea` action method which reacts to `Enter` key strokes, ie:

```
amount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        interest.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see how that method could work the way I have it.  I have the calculator as its own class, and CalcTest actually creates the Calculator object.  I would have to use amount.requestFocusInWindow() in CalcTest, which does not have the amount variable.

Comment: @user1873736 there are two methods described, which one do you refer to? What is `CalcTest`, it is not part of the posted code. Tweaking focus traversal is done on the top level `Window`. Alternatively, transferring `requestFocusInWindow` is done in action methods of text areas.

Comment: I was referring to requestFocusInWindow.  Where would I use it in the code to make it work?  The frame isn't ever initialized in the Calculator class.  It is created as an object in CalcTest, which does nothing but create that object.

Comment: @user1873736 I assume you're asking how to give initial focus to a component. Since you have to make sure the component is realized, you can call `requestFocusInWindow` when a component becomes visible, or when the frame is activated and gains focus. There is an example of both cases in the mentioned tutorial. It can also be done using focus traversal policy.

Comment: I figured out how to make requestFocusInWindow work right.  I created a method in Calculator that set focus, and then called it from CalcTest.  I have also set an actionLister on the Enter button that will change the focus between the four JTextFields (all buttons are now set to setFocusable(false)).  My real problem now (and hopefully the last), is how I tell the program to enter the buttonString into the focused object, instead of a statically referenced object.